# How to manually disable/enable mrtk v2 spatial awareness settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to manually enable or disable the spatial awareness of my HoloLens app.

I have this UX hologram that is relative to my position (and it follows as I move) that I need to interact with, but colliders that were made from spatial awareness-mesh observer due to real walls will block the UX holograms hindering me from interacting with them.
I could just move away from the wall so I could interact the UX holograms but enabling them or disabling them would be more professional.

I need the spatial awareness-mesh observer to be enabled so I can create holograms using collider, but I also want them to be disabled so I can easily maneuver and interact with my UX hologram.

I'm pretty sure we can just enable or disable the Spatial Awareness System, but I'm having a hard time researching the syntax of getting the Spatial Awareness System in order to manually enable/disable it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551271/enable-disable-spatial-mapping-at-runtime-in-mrtk2/56572347#56572347

Comment: If yes, I'l mark this as duplicate. If not, could you please post that you tried that solution and why it didn't work for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for finding this. I 'm gonna try this method now.. hope this work!

Comment: didn't help but this is the right track though..

Comment: hey, did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

So I think there are a few toggles here that are available, which I think Hernando addressed as well.

If you want to:

1) Totally disable the spatial awareness system (i.e. no meshes, no colliders, nothing)

Then following the code in the first half of this answer would do it for you:
[Enable/Disable Spatial Mapping at runtime in MRTK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551271/enable-disable-spatial-mapping-at-runtime-in-mrtk2/56572347#56572347)

2) Have meshes, but just no rendering of the meshes:

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/SpatialAwareness/UsageGuide.html#hiding-the-spatial-mesh

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to enable or disable the collision of the spatial awareness mesh, you first need to access the [**Meshes**](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness.IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserver.html) property of observer(To get the Observer, you can refer to the second code in this answer: [Enable/Disable Spatial Mapping at runtime in MRTK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551271/enable-disable-spatial-mapping-at-runtime-in-mrtk2/56572347#56572347) ), and then access the Collider property of the mesh object, which property is an instance of the **[MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider.html)** class. Finally, you can  enable/disable the collider with enabled property.